# Как написать WEB приложение на Java?

Tags: java

На Java программирую не так давно и хочется попробовать написать какое-то веб приложение. Развернуть сервер на томкат и небольшое CRUD приложение написать. Какие технологии нужно изучить, с чего начать?

Comment: для начала html css JS

Comment: Предлагаю начать с  JDBC и Java Servlet

Comment: Начать можно как с примитивных [JavaEE Сервлетов](https://metanit.com/java/javaee/1.1.php), там и с чего-то поинтереснее и функциональнее в виде [фреймворка Spring MVC](https://spring.io/quickstart); Но так способов написать веб-приложение на JavaEE разной степени изощренности достаточно много.

Comment: html, css это примитив, это знаю.. А что обычно сейчас выбирают? И можно ли сразу начать изучать Spring MVC не начиная Spring Core? Ну так сказать по ходу узнавать.

Comment: Ну легче наверное начать с Java Servlets и JSP, поскольку они достаточно простенькие. А по Spring придется брать либо книги, либо искать хороший туториал, иначе очень легко уплыть в дебри и не разобраться. Про порядок Core и MVC не подскажу к сожалению. Можно еще Struts глянуть, у них [вроде хороший туториал](https://struts.apache.org/getting-started/index.html), по первому взгляду.

Answer (score 2):

1. Базовым для Java web являются [сервлеты](https://habr.com/ru/post/333626/)
2. На него сверху накручиваются JSP (Java Server Pages)
3. Коли уж речь идет о CRUD - тут JDBC в помощь - без нее никак.

Когда все это осилите дальше речь пойдет о фреймворках ибо почти никто уже не пишет напрямую, все пишут в рамках какого-либо фреймворка. Их теперь великое множество.

- начните с JSF (Java Server Faces - раньше называлось JSP tags)
- потом переходите на [Struts](https://struts.apache.org/)
- когда осилите JDBC - самое время будет погрузиться в [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/orm/)
- Spring оставьте на закуску.

Comment: Наоборот, теперь надо начинать со Spring, а Struts2 оставить на десерт.